# Zoom control WordPress plugin Pronamic Google Maps shown incorrectly

Tags: wordpress, google-maps

I am using the [Pronamic Google Maps](http://wordpress.org/plugins/pronamic-google-maps/) WordPress plugin to show a location at my website.

It works, but the zoom control is shown incorrectly:

[image]

Comment: Why downvote this question? Where can I ask questions about WordPress?  At http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/138680/zoom-control-wordpress-plugin-pronamic-google-maps-shown-incorrectly they asked me to go to SO :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be a Google Maps-issue and can be fixed with some CSS-code: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/zoom-control-not-properly-shown

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of other plugins, which provide the same functionality, try different one, for example [Mappress Google Maps](http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/mappress-google-maps-for-wordpress).

It appears that this is issue, related to the plugin, post your question on plugin's forum thread.